# How to create statistical pie chart with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, java, html, sql, charts

I am trying to create a pie chart which will show the number of hall bookings in a month or year. The data should be dynamic with the pie chart.

Comment: It would take exactly one google search "dynamic pie chart java" to find an answer.

Comment: Well..I posted the question after doing the google search

Comment: Googled it, clicked the 2nd link, got linked to `JFreeChart` which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [c3 js](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html) a free one which has simple configurations to do it

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    }
});
```

If you want to change data you have to make an ajax call (may be) and assign it to c3 chart again.

We also have many libraries to do this which can be checked upon by googling